# Django: Font Awesome not loading on Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, heroku, font-awesome

I am having problems with font awesome on firefox, the problem is the cross-origin resource sharing. Most of the solutions for this problem included changing the .htaccess file, but I was not able to change it on heroku. Is there any other way of fix this problem?

Comment: Where are you hosting your static/media files?

Comment: I am hosting on Amazon

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your S3 CORS configuration.  There's a decent overview of the settings you might consider here:

http://schock.net/articles/2013/07/03/hosting-web-fonts-on-a-cdn-youre-going-to-need-some-cors/

I'd start with setting `<AllowedOrigin>...</AllowedOrigin>` to match your domain(s), adding as many rules as required to cover all your use cases.  And please don't use `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` as many tutorials suggest--that's very unsafe.